# BigCommerce: Pre-loading the cart functionality

Tags: shopify, cart, bigcommerce

I need a functionality to add multiple products to the cart by hitting only one URL. This functionality is provided in [Shopify](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/cart-page/cart-permalinks).

Is there any similar functionality in **BigCommerce** that I can use to add multiple products to cart using single URL?

Comment: you can maybe using ajax

Answer (score 1):

Hey so there is a couple of ways you might achieve this.

You can direct straight to the one-page checkout by doing something like...

```
{URL}/cart.php?action=buy&sku=SKU1&sku=SKU2
```

You could add the products to the cart by doing...

```
{URL}/cart.php?action=add&sku=SKU1&sku=SKU2
```

There are a couple of other options that you can [see here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/storefront/add-to-cart-urls#common-usage).

Answer (score 0):

Adding multiple products to the cart using a URL would require customization and be accomplished through ajax requests. It is not native functionality in Bigcommerce.